# Set custom scaling on Retina MacBook Pro (13inch)

Tags: display, resolution

I want my scaling to look like 2560x1600. Currently, according to Display preferences, it looks like 1680x1050, and that is the smallest option.

I want everything to be WAY WAY smaller. My eyes are super good and I bought a MacBook with a retina display for a reason - so I could fit more stuff on the screen.

Notice how in the attached screenshot underneath the picture of the MacBook, it says "Looks like 1680x1050". That is no good. I need to fit a lot of stuff on my screen at once.

An example is when I open up League of Legends in Retina resolution, the cursor becomes extremely tiny for 3 seconds. That is how I want my whole Mac to look like.

Is there any way to set the scaling to 100%, like you can in Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 15" MacBook Pro with Retina Display and by itself, the highest resolution I can set in System Preferences > Hardware > Display > Display > (o) Scaled, is 1920x1200. To get an even higher resolution, e.g 2880x1800 I use a third-party utility named [Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12). It's available in the App Store for free.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed